# Battery info from the Blackberry 10 SDK

Tags: blackberry-10, battery

I tried this code:

```
battery_info_t **pointer=NULL;
battery_get_info(pointer);
return battery_info_get_time_to_empty(*pointer); // needs simple pointer (*pointer)
```

My question is: how can i convert **pointer to *pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this usage the battery_info_... function calls take a pointer to a battery_info_t type, so you would declare pointer as that and use it as the argument to those calls. To set pointer to the correct value you pass a pointer to it to battery_get_info(). You must also free the memory allocated to pointer when you are done:

```
battery_info_t    *pointer = NULL;
battery_get_info(&pointer);
int t = battery_info_get_time_to_empty(pointer);
battery_free_info(&pointer);
return t;
```

Comment: works, but returns the same thing 65535, thanks for the code, i guess it returns that because its on an emulator.

Comment: Have you used the simulator controller to adjust the charge level of the battery? However, even with that there are some things that it just doesn't make sense to simulate.

Comment: yes, i tried moving the charge level from that controller, but still the same value

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1) as I mention above, they may not have found any way to simulate 'time to empty' that makes sense; 2) the API has been stubbed out to does not actually have the code in place yet. If I have time I'll try this on my Dev Alpha and let you know what I get.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
battery_info_t *pointer=NULL;     
battery_get_info(&pointer);    
return battery_info_get_time_to_empty(pointer);
```

But returns `65535`, on an emulator, so i can't tell if it works or not, because i don have an BB10...